# No body class in Wordpress on specific server

Tags: wordpress, apache, nginx, plesk

I have the strangest problem, I get no body classes on different Wordpress sites on a specific server. When I'm developing the site (http://parka-jassen.nl) local on my Xampp installation, all is well. But when I upload it to my web server i get no body class (just have ).

The same problem also occurs with other Wordpress sites on the same server, so I figure this must be a server problem. I'm using CentOS 6.5 with Plesk 11.5.30, Apache 2.2.15, nginx 1.5.0, PHP 5.3.3 and MySQL 5.1.71.

WordPress adds body classes with the body_class function. But also when I manual enter a body class (for example I set  in the code) then I still get an empty class displayed in the code.

To be certain I tried different themes and deactivated all my plugins, but nothing offered a solution. Is there anyone with an idea what this could be?

Thank you very much in advance!

Jeroen

Comment: Are you logged in on your local development server? I believe sometimes that the <body> class is different if you are logged in, compared to logged out.

Comment: Hi David, yes you're correct, you get an extra class (I beleive something like logged-in) when you're logged in. But in my case that doesn't matter, I get no class at all whether I'm logged in or logged out.

Comment: Why do you have two "body" tags on site? Also, check auto_prepend_file in your PHP (http://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.auto-prepend-file) I've see some strange ad banner when I've open your site in first time, when I've reload page banner is gone. It's quite strange for me.